# Add ajax to existing page with jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I need help with an advanced search I implemented into a new existing page system.

It seems there is a problem with the existing jquery ui on the page:

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
```

When I enter my code the page isn't working properly anymore.
My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#warenkorb_suche_feld').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#warenkorb_suche_feld').val();
        $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#warenkorb_suche_feld").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });
});
```

The search script works fine but I need to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And after this page stops working. What can I do to get this stuff working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way does this code fail?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  When you debug with your browser's debugging tools, what specifically happens?  Also, jQuery's `.live()` is *ancient*, now is probably a good time to modernize the code.  Additionally, does this example imply that you're loading two different versions of jQuery on the page?  If so, you should only need one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you review the Console, so you see any errors? I do not see where `search()` is executed.

Comment: It sounds like you are overwriting an existing jQuery with another jQuery, but there isn't a [mcve] for us to see for sure. jQuery 1.7.1 is positively ancient and unsupported so you shouldn't be using it anyway.

Comment: @David thanks, you opened my eyes. There were two versions of jquery, a much newer version 1.10.2 was running and .live() destroyed the whole page. I changed it into [code]$("input#warenkorb_suche_feld").on("keyup", null, function(e) {[/code] and now it's working fine. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following. I was not able to test it.

```
$(function() {
  function search(term, callback) {
    $('b#search-string').text(term);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "search.php",
      data: {
        query: term
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("ul#results").html(html);
        if(callback && (typeof callback == "function")){
          callback();
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

  $('div.icon').click(function() {
    $('input#warenkorb_suche_feld').focus();
  });

  $("input#warenkorb_suche_feld").on("keyup", function(e) {
    // Set Search String
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    // Do Search
    if (search_string.length > 0) {
      $("ul#results, h4#results-text").fadeOut(400, function() {
        search(search_string, function() {
          $("ul#results, h4#results-text").fadeIn();
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This makes use of the `complete` callback for `.fadeOut()`. So once it has faded, it will then run the search. I added a Callback in the search so that once the AJAX has completed, it will reveal the results with `.fadeIn()`.

You may want to consider adjusting the `length` condition. This ensures